# Trouble with Twitter API using Python

Tags: python, twitter, http-status-code-404

I'm having some trouble in this python code:

```
import twitter
twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
trends = twitter_search.trends()
```

The error (404 page not found) is right here: 
[image]

I'm using this package: http://github.com/sixohsix/twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Twitter API documentation for the `trends` call](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/trends) the domain should be `api.twitter.com`:

```
import twitter
twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="api.twitter.com")
print twitter_search.trends()

{u'trends': [{u'url': u'http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23weedcommandments', 
 u'name': u'#weedcommandments'}, ...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ! For further record, I took this code from the book Mining the Social Web.

Comment: The new API requires the you indicate where in the world you happen to be.  See http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920010203

Answer (score 2):

Because of the new API change, you need to use this program:

```
import twitter
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(domain="api.twitter.com", api_version='1')
WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
world_trends = twitter_api.trends._(WORLD_WOE_ID) 
trends = world_trends()
print [trend['name'] for trend in trends[0]['trends']]
```

This is based, in part, on the [book errata website](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920010203).

Comment: @vaidabhishek, In which line?

Comment: In this line world_trends = twitter_api.trends._(WORLD_WOE_ID)

Comment: It's setting the location for your trends, using the Yahoo "Where On Earth" ID system, see http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html

Comment: Okay. But tell you exactly tell me the nature of HTTP request this line is expected to generate.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout the updated IPython Notebook for Chapter 1 of Mining the Social Web that shows an updated example for this workflow and API call as well as a little bit of other context that is compatible with Twitter's v1.1 API. See http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web/master/ipython_notebooks/Chapter1.ipynb for a read-only version of the notebook.